# Docker Cleanup - Can I delete old directories under /var/lib/docker/containers

Tags: docker

I have 16 docker containers running in my system which stores a lot of data under`/var/lib/docker/overlay2/<id>`(around 30 GB per-directory.. Total 30*16 GB). Primarily space is consumed by `diff` and `merged` directories inside it.

Every time I do a `docker-compose down` followed by  `docker-compose up`, it creates another set of 16 directories and starts storing data under that. **But it does not clean up old overlay2 directories. This leads to a space crunch**

1. Please let me know if I can do rm -rf /var/lib/docker/overlay2/
   of old directories or how I can free up space.
2. Do I need to wait for a couple of hours after `docker-compose down` to
   reclaim space?

Note: I did a `docker system prune -a` also.

Comment: `rm -rf /var/lib/docker/overlay2/` are being duplicated indicates that the old ones are being obsolete. Remove them and check (not before taking a back-up though!)

Comment: /var/lib/docker/overlay2 is not duplicated, I meant directories under overlay2 are not cleaned up when containers are removed

Comment: Are they supposed to be? If yes, then go ahead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1)Please let me know if I can do rm -rf /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ of
> old directories or how I can free up space.

**Only you can decide that**.
When I suspect unused data for a `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/foo123` folder, I first inspect the content of that folder. It contains generally image content. With modification date of files and content of files , I have a high probability to determinate if the folder is useless.
When I am sure that it is useless, I delete it with `rm -rf ...`. Note that the delete may fail because file mounting, in that case I identify them and unmount them first.
If I am not sure that it is useless, I perform a backup before such as  `cp -a /var/lib/docker/overlay2/foo123 /var/lib/docker/overlay2/backup-foo123` before deleting

> 2)Do I need to wait for a couple of hours after docker-compose down to
> reclaim space?

With just Docker, no at all.  Data have to be explicitly removed (such as : `docker container rm FOO`, `docker system prune`, `docker system prune -a`, `docker image rm FOO` and so for).
But Docker is not perfect. So sometimes you may have stale data.
Generally from time to time, I inspect docker big folders with a `du -sh */ | sort -h`.